# Is the EEPROM the best alternative for store non-volatile values with Arduino?

Tags: eeprom

SD-cards are capable of store values even if it is turned off.

I don't know what is the time that a EEPROM can keep a value in it's memory, but of course are better than the volatile memory.

There are some others ways of store non-volatile values for arduino?

Which of these need hardware built-in and which doesn't?

Are the EEPROM the best alternative (in terms of facility, durability, and cost) for store non-volatile values when we talk about Arduinos (or even microcontrollers in general)?

Comment: the best alternative for store non-volatile values. Updated question

Comment: Do you know what is a SQL?

Comment: I mean what is the best way to store non-volatile values in the Arduino, dear

Comment: it is a language for manipulating databases ... it is kind of irrelevant to the question

Comment: So, don't is the EEPROM and the SQL used for the same thing? Store non-volatile values?

Comment: instead of getting caught up in details like a grammar nazi, try to catch the idea behind the question

Comment: you are not understanding. . one person's `best` may be another person's `don't care` ... for example, one person may only be interested in data retention... another person may be interested in write speed ... etc.etc. .... so, what is your definition of `best`?

Comment: So you can respond like that: If you are interested in data retention, do like this... If you are interested in write speed, thus. In this way, we can have a broad understanding of the question. I am not able to define my question more than this, because if I could, I would be likely to respond it by myself.

Comment: then the EEPROM is not suitable because it has a limited number of write cycles available before it fails

Comment: I wouldn't say alternative, it's fundamentally different. EEPROM is basically stand alone (on chip, or on board) and small. For full blown SQL you'll probably need network connection and server with SQL. Alternative for EEPROM can be FRAM (almost unlimited writes), flash (size but less writes), sd card or similar (even bigger, also limited writes).

Comment: @jsotola thanks. Now i appreciate your response.

Comment: `don't is the EEPROM and the SQL used for the same thing?` ... you are confusing a hardware component with software ... a comparison between EEPROM and SD card would make more sense

Comment: @KIIV I am grateful. Let me do a question. Do sd card need hardware aditional parts or no? The FRAM kind of store and the flash you said, need aditional hardware too?

Comment: @jsotola ok, i will improve the question

Comment: Usually needs few wires and maybe slot or so. But no need for full blown server and network (another computer)

Comment: Question improved.

Comment: Your question got down-voted because asking what is the "best" thing is pretty subjective. You may as well ask what is the best car to buy. If you are more specific next time you may get a better response and less argument. A more general question like "what are the advantages and disadvantages of using EEPROM?" could probably be answered with a Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EEPROM on the Atmega328P (such as on the Arduino Uno) holds 1KB (1024 bytes) and has a documented write/erase cycle of 100,000 writes.

So, if your application only needs to store 1024 bytes in a non-volatile way, and you do not plan to write more than 100,000 times then that is suitable.

The sort of things I would use EEPROM for are remembering settings (eg. fan speed, oven temperature, a password for accessing WiFi, that sort of thing).

I also personally use it for "remembering" RFID card codes for access to my house. In my experience, using it for that purpose, it has never "forgotten" a code. According to the datasheet it will retain data for 100 years at 25°C.

It is convenient because you don't need any extra hardware.

---

Other alternatives are SPI or I2C based external EEPROM, such as NVRAM (non-volatile RAM) which would have larger capacity, but you would need to connect it. That would likely be about 5 wires and somewhere to put the chip. An example of that is [Adafruit I2C FRAM Breakout](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2c-fram-breakout/wiring-and-test).

[image: FRAM breakout board]

---

You could use a micro-SD card, which I have used on [another project](https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12106) to record temperature readings every 15 minutes. This has a lot more capacity than EEPROM, and then you can just take the SD card out and read it in an ordinary PC. This needs extra hardware (eg. a holder for the SD card and possibly voltage-level shifters). However you can buy that for around $20, and it is easy enough to hook up.

[image: Micro SD card breakout board]

---

I don't know how SQL got into the discussion under the question, but that is a language (Structured Query Language) and not a piece of hardware.

---

Another alternative, if you don't particularly want portability, is to send your data along a connection to your PC, and record the data there. Conceivably WiFi could be used for that.

---

### Speed

Speed-wise, I would say EEPROM is the fastest because it is natively inside the chip. Other alternatives required sending messages along wires (I2C, SPI, or maybe USB) to somewhere else and that takes time.

Writing is slower than reading, because writing involves using electricity to make a chemical change in the chip (turning a 1-bit into a 0-bit) but it is still quite fast.

Comment: Try FRAM either SPI or I2C, read and writes in the billions. 32K x 8. Here is a link: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2c-fram-breakout/wiring-and-test

Comment: @Gil Nice. Easy to use and ridiculously cheap. I might order myself one ... or a few. :)
My only problem with it would be that you would need to fiddle around to get the data off it (if that was a requirement). Using an SD card makes that part simpler.

Comment: It works like external EEPROM but no delays for read or write. You can do one location at a time if wanted. In general, ferroelectric-based memory technologies (FeRAM, FeFET, and FTJ) exhibit fast write/read speed, long retention, high endurance, and low write energy consumption.